# Can we use CCMenuItemToggle in UIActionsheet ?( cocos2d-iphone)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I 'm developing an Application where i need toggle buttons for Sound ON/OFF,and i'm using UIActionsheet.

any demos/tutorial would be highly appreciated.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

No. Cocos2d views don't work with UIKit (barring the workaround of adding `CCDirector.view` as a subview). Moreover, `UIActionSheet` only allows normal buttons, not switch/toggle buttons. You might want to create your own view that looks like `UIActionSheet`, but supports more operations like a toggle button.

Comment: I have already applied the alternative though i wasn't assure. 
You're little late ;)

Comment: Add it as an answer then :)